# C# Creating an array of methods

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

Well, been looking for this but since I cannot be more specific, Google seems out of answer, so I decided to ask here.

Anyway to create an array of methods that returns a value ?

Like

```
methodArray[0].Invoke();
```

Can I use delegate ? If so, how ?

like if i have 2 methods that needs same parameters

```
dobule Add(double number)
{
//code
}
double Remove(double number)
{
//code
}
```

what do i need to do in order to invoke them with index ( I dont want to deal with switch statement)

Comment: None of them seems to work for me.

Comment: You will need to show your code and tell us in what way it does not work. The question/answers I linked to tell how to do it.

Comment: Action is a delegate and i can neither use it with List<> nor Action[]

Comment: There is a right way to do it, and many, many wrong ways. Without seeing your code, it's pretty hard to guess how you've done it wrong.

Comment: @user1926930: you very much *can* use delegates and `Action` objects with `List<>`. Again, show us some actual code (edit it into your question) and then maybe we can actually help you.

Comment: There is no need for actual code, which i don't have one.I'm just wondering how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of `Func`s.  However, this is limited to methods that all have the same signature (return type and number and type of parameters).

If you have several methods that don't take any parameters you can use it like this:

```
var methods = new List<Func<T>>();
```

where T is the lowest common object in the return value, which might just be `object`.

```
var methods = new List<Func<object>>();
```

If you just want to call `void` methods, or aren't worried about the return type, you can use `Action` instead:

```
var methods = new List<Action>();
```

Either way, you can then invoke them like so:

```
foreach(var method in methods){
   var result = method();
   //or if you don't care about return type
   method();
}
```

You might also find this post useful: [How do you use Func<> and Action<> when designing applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537404/how-do-you-use-func-and-action-when-designing-applications)

**UPDATED**
The example below shows how you can use this technique with your `Add` and `Remove` method:

```
    public double Add(double number) { return 0;}
    public double Remove(double number) { return 0; }

    public void Example()
    {
        //Array of methods
        var methods = new Func<double, double>[]
        {
            n => Add(n),
            n => Remove(n)
        };

        //Invoking methods
        var number = 0d;
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            method(number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using the generic type 'System.Action<T>' requires 1 type arguments 

This is the error.

Comment: Then use the non generic `Action` if you don't need to pass method parameters

Comment: explain more maybe ? non generic ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if we have a method like this

double Add()
{
//code
}

how can i add this to action list or create an action list ?

Comment: Does add take parameters?

Comment: yep, just one parameter.

Comment: and what type is this one parameter?

Comment: Please update your original question with the full signature for `Add`

Comment: Ok, did what you said.