# When should I use C# Generic Func<T,Tresult>?

Tags: c#, generics, func

I have been looking at C#'s Generic function delegates (Func) feature.

Example:

```
// Instantiate delegate to reference UppercaseString method
Func<string, string> convertMethod = UppercaseString;
string name = "Dakota";

// Use delegate instance to call UppercaseString method
Console.WriteLine(convertMethod(name));
```

I'm struggling to think of a real life scenario where they might be useful in my own applications. So I thought I would put the question out there. \

I'd greatly appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: check the source code of linq ``Where()`` and other extesnion methods on ``IEnumerable<T>``, you will get understanding where its useful and how to use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use Func<> and Action<> when designing applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537404/how-do-you-use-func-and-action-when-designing-applications)

Comment: i combine dictionary and func (`Dictionary<string , Func<...>>`) to do some operations for specific keys when reading  unmanaged resources.

Comment: This is general called higher order functions. Read about it and you will be enlightened once you grasp it. I promise.

Comment: Anywhere you use `switch`, replace the whole thing with `Dictionary<string , Func<...>>` or `Dictionary<string , Action<...>>` to hugely simplify your code. This is my single biggest use of `Func<>`

Comment: @BenN: I give this user the benefit of the doubt, for some reason I feel a willingness to learn :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say one needs to time method calls for reporting purposes. Placing the timing code inside the function is not feasible for maintenance reasons.

So by using the `Func` call one can do the time operation and not interfere:

```
static void Time<T>(Func<T> work)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var result = work();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed + ": " + result);
}
```

Then call it with our function to be timed

```
Time(() => { return "Jabberwocky"; });
```

Result:

```
 00:00:00.0000926: Jabberwocky
```

---

Here is an example use of `Funct<T,TResult>` using the same time motif to time regex vs string.split

```
var strData = "The rain in Spain";

Time((str) => { return Regex.Split(str, @"\s"); }, strData);
Time((str) => { return str.Split(); },             strData);
```

Here is the setup

```
static void Time<T,S>(Func<T,S> work, T strToSplit)
{
   var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   var result = work(strToSplit);
   sw.Stop();

    var joined = string.Join(", ", result as string[]);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", sw.Elapsed, joined);

}
```

And the results

```
00:00:00.0000232 : The, rain, in, Spain
00:00:00.0000021 : The, rain, in, Spain
```

---

Updating this answer for 2017. This is not a `Func` but its non return sibling `Action`; I have found I do a basic form of logging on my classes where I use *Dependency Injection* from a consumer such as this:

```
Action<string> ReportIt  { get; set; }

public void ReportStatus(Action<string> statusReporter)
{
    ReportIt = statusReporter;   
}
```

The idea is that status reporting is optional, so later in the code I check to see if it is vialble and if so I give status:

```
 ReportIt?.Invoke("Running - Connection initiated");
```

The consumer of the class calls it such as

```
 piperInstance.ReportStatus( Console.WriteLine );
```

which could also be expressed as

```
 piperInstance.ReportStatus((str) => { Console.WriteLine(str); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

*A bit long for a comment (making a community wiki)*

The best way to explain the use case is for the fucntional `map` function.

In C# the is called `Select`.

Say you have a list a strings, `map` will allow you to to change the strings.

As in you example:

`somewords.Select(Uppercase)` or

`somewords.Select(x = Uppercase(x))` or

`somewords.Select(x => x.ToUpper())`

But it is not limited to string to string conversions. Say you want to get a list of the of the length of all string, you can simply do:

`somewords.Select(x => x.Length)`

Above will return a list of integers (or whatever is used in your language).

Once you start combining the this with other higher order functions, things become fun :)

Going back to the previous example, but say you want the length of the longest string. You have many options to do it:

```
somewords.Select(x => x.Length).Max()
somewords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).First()
// or even
somewords.Max(x => x.Length)
```

And probably a few more I missed. In the end it all helps you expressing your intent without having to do a lot of extra work (like the last example).

**Note:**

In every case above, `x => x.Length` could have been replaced by any function that did the same as getting the length, say `Foo`. Eg

```
int Foo(string s)
{
  return s.Length;
}
```

So `somewords.Max(Foo)` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Saw an interesting real-life example just now:

```
public static List<Transaction> ReadAll(Settings settings, Func<string, FileInfo[]> getFilesOfType)
{
     FileInfo[] files = getFilesOfType("CashRevenue");
     // does stuff with files
}
```

which is called by

```
var transactions = FileParser.ReadAll(m_status.FilesByType)
```

which provides the function FilesByType as a parameter

```
public FileInfo[] FilesByType (string type)
{
     return result = Files.Where(f => f.Type == type)
                 .Select(f => new FileInfo(f.LocalPath))
                 .ToArray();
}
```

where Files is a collection property which can be filtered with the string parameter to FilesByType